# How well known is the word "butler"?

Tags: common-word

I'm about to launch a new web service, and currently we're still looking for a name. I thought it would be nice to call it a "digital butler" - my collaborator from Dubai, however, pointed out, that a big part of the world does not know the world "butler".

How true is this?

Comment: Unless there has been a huge, globally representative poll on the subject, I am not sure how we could answer the question in its current form (without conducting a huge, globally representative poll ourselves). That being said, I would like to point out that even *I* know the word *butler*, and I'm an evil communist whose mother tongue ain't English.

Comment: @RegDwight I get your point. However, I was not asking for a statistically representative poll, but just wondering if you've heard of this already as it was completely new to me that some people might not know this word.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the meaning of your web service has to be crystal clear in itself (did you understand "Yahoo!" or "Google" at first?).

The naming, *combined* with a good logo, a simple design and a clear offer are what make your web service relevant.

Comment: +1 but I need to add: only as long as the name is easily spelled and remembered.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [well known web site](http://uk.ask.com/) that has gambled on the familiarity of the concept.

Arguably they [lost that gamble](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/7990296.stm), but still.

Comment: Indeed, though Wodehouse's Jeeves was a gentleman's gentleman or valet rather than a butler, even if he could "buttle with the best of them".